Siding leaking, contractor suggesting spray foam insulation to fix it?
We have several leaks around the siding of an old 1950s house. Unclear exactly where it's coming from, the exterior is unsheathed, with wood siding under stucco. Siding is soft in places, and some of the framing is soft too. Moisture levels around 40.
A contractor suggested replacing the soft framing, and then insulating with spray foam to stop the leaks thus avoiding taking off the stucco.
This doesn't sound right to me? Wouldn't an air gap be important in this situation and is the fix not more likely to be in fixing the leak in the roof or resealing the stucco?

if there's a leak in the roof.

I’m not absolutely clear on the source of the leak… is it the roof? Is it the stucco? You need to deal with the root cause, not put bandaids on.
